# Selecting all column names where value is greater than another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the column names of each column in a pandas dataframe where the value is greater than that of another column.

For example, if I have the following dataframe:

```
   A  B  C  D  threshold
0  1  3  3  1  2
1  2  3  6  1  5
2  9  5  0  2  4
```

For each row I would like to return the names of the columns where the values are greater than the threshold, so I would have:

```
0: B, C
1: C
2: A, B
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: One way is to make use of `apply`.

Comment: @FClubb If you have lots of data, you may want to check out my solution which is more than an order of magnitude faster than the others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a large increase in speed you can use NumPy's vectorized `where` function.

```
s = np.where(df.gt(df['threshold'],0), ['A, ', 'B, ', 'C, ', 'D, ', ''], '')
pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s])

0    B, C
1       C
2    A, B
dtype: object
```

There is more than an order of magnitude speedup vs @jezrael and MaxU solutions when using a dataframe of 100,000 rows. Here I create the test DataFrame first.

```
n = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, 5)), 
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'threshold'])
```

#### Timings

```
%%timeit
>>> s = np.where(df.gt(df['threshold'],0), ['A, ', 'B, ', 'C, ', 'D, ', ''], '')
>>> pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s])
280 ms ± 5.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
>>> df1 = df.drop('threshold', 1).gt(df['threshold'], 0)
>>> df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.index[x]),axis=1)
3.15 s ± 82.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
>>> x = df.drop('threshold',1)
>>> x.T.gt(df['threshold']).agg(lambda c: ', '.join(x.columns[c]))
3.28 s ± 145 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.drop('threshold', 1).gt(df['threshold'], 0)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.index[x]),axis=1)
print (df1)
0    B, C
1       C
2    A, B
dtype: object
```

Similar solution:

```
df1 = df.drop('threshold', 1).gt(df['threshold'], 0).stack().rename_axis(('a','b'))
        .reset_index(name='boolean')
a = df1[df1['boolean']].groupby('a')['b'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (a)
   a     b
0  0  B, C
1  1     C
2  2  A, B
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way:

```
In [99]: x = df.drop('threshold',1)

In [100]: x
Out[100]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  3  3  1
1  2  3  6  1
2  9  5  0  2

In [102]: x.T.gt(df['threshold']).agg(lambda c: ', '.join(x.columns[c]))
Out[102]:
0    B, C
1       C
2    A, B
dtype: object
```