# Find first value in dataframe's columns greater than another

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking for the most efficient way to find the first value in all columns of a pandas df, from left to right (**0,1,2,3**), for each row, that is greater than another column (**t**), and put the corresponding column label in a new column (**val**). If no column value is greater, then I want **0** instead.

For some reason I could not find anything simple and efficient (as the real table is really big).

E.g:

**Initial table:**

```
     t    0    1    2    3
JAN  3  1.9  2.1  2.6  2.9
FEB  6  2.0  4.0  5.0  9.0
MAR  2  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0
APR  4  1.5  3.0  6.0  2.0
```

**Final table:**

```
     t    0    1    2    3   val
JAN  3  1.9  2.1  2.6  2.9   0
FEB  6  2.0  4.0  5.0  9.0   3
MAR  2  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0   1
APR  4  1.5  3.0  6.0  2.0   2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = """
     t    0    1    2    3
JAN  3  1.9  2.1  2.6  2.9
FEB  6  2.0  4.0  5.0  9.0
MAR  2  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0
APR  4  1.5  3.0  6.0  2.0
"""

# Read in the string
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)

# Find all columns greater than your threshold column
s = np.where(df.gt(df['t'],0), ['', 0, 1, 2, 3], np.nan)

# Convert to dataframe, find the first instance, fill the 
# rest with zeros and make a new column
df['vals'] = pd.DataFrame(s).min(axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int).values

# Which yields your expected result
print(df)
#     t    0    1    2    3  vals
#JAN  3  1.9  2.1  2.6  2.9     0
#FEB  6  2.0  4.0  5.0  9.0     3
#MAR  2  1.0  3.0  4.0  4.0     1
#APR  4  1.5  3.0  6.0  2.0     2
```

I based this off the answer to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935143/selecting-all-column-names-where-value-is-greater-than-another-column-in-pandas), which suggested that this technique is faster than a few other options.

Comment: Apologies for the mismatch between the two tables... The solution you offered works perfectly and was lighting fast :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the original tables to match, and have removed your commentary in reference to that discrepancy accordingly.