# Find index of first row whose value matches a condition set by another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of two columns:

```
    x   y
0   1   2
1   2   4
2   3   6
3   4   8
4   5  10
5   6  12
6   7  14
7   8  16
8   9  18
9  10  20
```

I would like to add a column whose value is the index of the first value to meet the following condition: `y >= x`. For example, for row 2 (`x = 3`), the first `y` value greater or equal to 3 is 4 so the output of `z` for row 2 is (index) 1. I expect the final table to look like:

```
    x   y   z
0   1   2   0
1   2   4   0
2   3   6   1
3   4   8   1
4   5  10   2
5   6  12   2
6   7  14   3
7   8  16   3
8   9  18   4
9  10  20   4
```

It should be noted that both `x` and `y` are sorted if that should make the solution easier.

I have seen a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979069/find-first-value-in-dataframes-columns-greater-than-another/50980050) but I could not translate it to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), which assumes `df['y']` is sorted:

```
df['z'] = np.searchsorted(df['y'], df['x'])
```

Output:

```
    x   y  z
0   1   2  0
1   2   4  0
2   3   6  1
3   4   8  1
4   5  10  2
5   6  12  2
6   7  14  3
7   8  16  3
8   9  18  4
9  10  20  4
```